# oracle trigger ORA-04091: table is mutating

Tags: oracle

I have a Table DWZ with date column ZM, need to set the trigger when date is smaller than DZZ date in the same table.
Guess I have an error in code, because I get "ORA-04091: table TOMEK.ZM is mutating, trigger/function may not see it" when try to change the DWZ date.
Please help me correct it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SDW
BEFORE UPDATE OF DWZ
ON ZM
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  minimum DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT DZZ INTO minimum
  FROM ZM z
  WHERE z.DWZ = :NEW.DWZ;
  IF :NEW.DWZ <= minimum THEN
    Raise_application_error(-20201,'Date=' ||:NEW.DWZ|| ' is wrong');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: A row-level trigger on a table, `zm` in this case, cannot generally query that table.  Is `dwz` the primary key?  If so, do you just want to compare `:new.dmz <= :new.dzz`?  If not, is your `select into` statement supposed to have some sort of aggregate function (`min` perhaps)?  Having the data in one row depend on data in other rows in the table generally implies a data model problem so the solution is generally to fix the data model.  You can work around it with multiple triggers, a package, and a collection, but that gets ugly.

Comment: signs should be opposite, but I just want to compare :new.dwz >= dzz in the same row. Primary key is on other UNIQUE INDEX created on that table.

Comment: it is a homework, it can be ugly...

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to compare the data between two columns in the same row, just use the `:new` pseudorecord.  There is no need to query the table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SDW
  BEFORE UPDATE OF DWZ
  ON ZM
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.DWZ <= :new.dzz THEN
    Raise_application_error(-20201,'Date=' ||:NEW.DWZ|| ' is wrong');
  END IF;
END;
```

Of course, in the real world, you'd never use a trigger to do this sort of thing.  You'd use a check constraint.